# Let button have the same size

Tags: android, layout

My layout code as below:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Phone Files" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Photos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

How to let the btn_left and btn_right have the same size?

Comment: If there is no any more importance then why you not give the same size to that both button ? I mean android:width="50dp" like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no any more importance of weight then just remove the weight from your layout and give equal size to that both Button.
See Below:

**Edited:**

Create the String in to your string.xml file
as like:

```
 <string name="button_name">Phone "\n" Files</string>
```

then Put the Below code and it will show you the Button with two line text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout         
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"         
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"         
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"         
        android:gravity="center_vertical"         
        android:orientation="horizontal" >          

        <Button             
            android:id="@+id/btn_left"             
            android:layout_width="100dp"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:text="@string/button_name"/>          
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/list_title"             
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:layout_weight="0.5"             
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"             
            android:text="Photos"             
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />          
        <Button             
            android:id="@+id/btn_right"             
            android:layout_width="100dp"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:text="Save" />     
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it works as you want.
Thanks.
Enjoy.

Comment: i m wondering  does linearlayout usesS
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"         
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Comment: But I want the left button text show 2 rows, and the right one only 1 row.

Comment: Ok I have solved your problem. Please wait for my edited Answer.

Comment: @brian : If you got the solution then you can accept the answer so that can help others. and also give upvote with all sutable answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:weightSum="2.5"` as an attribute to your LinearLayout tag and change the layout_width values of all three widgets to `android:layout_width="0dip"`

Comment: Edited, completely overlooked the fact that you had weights set to fill_parent, try changing those to 0dip

Comment: "0dip" in attribute "layout_weight" cannot be converted to float

Comment: Wow.. layout_width, not layout_weight, my apologies.. trying to do too many things at once

Comment: It make the button become very width, but I did not want it.